# Xamarin iOS api call fails suddenly when app goes to background or notification panel drawn

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin iOS , when the api call starts requesting, when we switch app to background or the notification panel is drawn from the top, suddenly api call fails. Api returns bad request.No issues with foreground calls. This does not happen in android. api calls will be successful in background. When `DidEnterBackground` method has hit, api call will be failed by the time.I am using iOS OS 13.6 device. Forms has the latest version.Please help...

Comment: Did you get any error logs? It would be better to post the relevant code which will be helpful to find out the cause .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Getting this:  {System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d4] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iO…}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iOS build settings,Changing the HttpClient Implementation option from NSUrlSession to Managed  fixed the issue!!!